# Ember-rails rails 4 on Heroku - uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'extend' of undefined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ember.js, ruby-on-rails-4

I've created a base kickstarter project of using ember-rails with rails 4.0 and for it to be all ready for heroku. I've added the standard to-dos app within the kickstarter project.

You can find the github repo here: https://github.com/jonathanchrisp/kickstarter_rails4_ember_heroku

When I run the site locally it works perfectly, however once deployed to heroku it has a console error which states:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'extend' of undefined

The js should all be required in the appropriate order. I don't understand why this doesn't work.

You can find the heroku instance running here: http://warm-stream-2415.herokuapp.com/

Anyone come across this..?

Comment: I'm having the same error when I deploy ember-rails to heroku. Did you ever work this out?